# App script not returning object in proper order

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, google-apps-script

Good afternoon everybody,

I am fairly new to coding. I got into coding because of for the love of problem solving and to improve my business management better. If I may appear rude, please forgive me. I'm looking to learn from the best.

In my script editor, I have the following code.

```
var parDetails = [];

//To add participant data into participant log
function addparDetails(code, name, dob, gender, health){ 
    parDetails.push({code, name, dob, gender, health});
    return parDetails;
    }

//Participant details [updated]
  for (let i = 0; i <= 1; i++){
    addparDetails("123151", "John Doe", "18 June 2000","M", "Asthma");
}
Logger.log(parDetails);

It should return in the order of 
{code = 123151
 name = John Doe
 date = 18 June 2000
 Gender = M
 Health = Asthma}

However, it keeps returning in this order 
{dob = 18 June 2000
 name = John Doe
 gender = M
 code = 123151
 Health = asthma}

sometimes it can also be in a different order|
```

Could someone explain why is it this way ? If you require any further clarification please do let me know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `parDetails.push({code, name, dob, gender, health});`

In this line, you are pushing a javascript [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object) to the array.

Objects are key value pairs and the order in which the keys will show up is not defined. When you do `{a}`, it is same as `{a: a}`.

For example,

```
var a = 5
var b = {a} // Implicitly it is doing b = {a: 5}
console.log(b.a) // To access the value
```

You cannot rely on the order of the keys.

Comment: So in order to get the value i would like in order, I would have to access the properties of the object one by one? 

For instance:
console.log(parDetails.code);
console.log(parDetails.name);

and etc?

Comment: Yes. You can also put all of it in the same console.log(parDetails.code, parDetails.name, parDetails.dob ...). One other way would be to alphabetically log them by using Object.keys(parDetails) but that would need complex logging logic and I would not recommend it.

Comment: That was my previous code method. I'm looking to improve it because it was long and tedious even thou simple. Look like I have no choice temporarily until I've learned more :(

Comment: You can use a Map instead if you absolutely want guaranteed order in logging.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 0):

It's the way `objects` work in javascript. The order of their key-value pairs isn't guaranteed to stay the same. You should try `Map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map.

> The `Map` object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys.

Comment: Yikes .. I have not learned about that yet. I'll read it up and see if it can help me. Thanks !